# How to set Listview ScrollBar To Left In android API 8?

Tags: android, scrollbar, scroll-position

I need to use left Side Scroolbar in android api 8
the code bellow works in upper API :

```
mListView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);
```

But Not Works In API 8

How To Fix It ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in ur xml..add this to ur `ListView`

```
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
```